# PostgreSQL requires password after changing Rails DB setup from database name to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Changed the DB setup of Rails (`config/database.yml`) from:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
```

to:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  url: postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/my_app_development
```

Started getting the following error:

```
rails db:migrate:reset
=> rails aborted!
=> PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `pg_hba.conf` has different rules for this scenario. The following line might look like it enables all connections

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer (or trust)
```

But there can be other offending ones, in my case:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Changing this line from md5 to trust resolved the issue. Keep in mind that this is not safe.